# No output for sorted and searched array

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, binary-search

I've been studying everything I've gone over in my first semester of programming. I have a final coming up so I've been trying to write sample programs combining everything I've learned to prepare. The program below is supposed to read in names from a file, sort them via bubble search, and then prompt the user to enter a name, which the binary search will look for and tell you if the person is a friend or not.

My problem is, when I type a name, I am only prompted to type the name again. There is no output.

Please keep in mind that everything in here is mostly what I've learned so far (so I do not know how to use vectors, pointers, etc).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void bubblesort(string[], const int);
void search(string[], const int);
int sub = 0;

int main()
{
 const int maxsize = 100;
 string friendArray[maxsize];

 ifstream friends;
 friends.open("myFriends.dat");

 while (sub < maxsize && getline(friends, friendArray[sub]))
   sub++;


 bubblesort(friendArray, sub);
 search(friendArray, maxsize);


 system("pause");
 return 0;
}



void bubblesort(string *array, const int size)
{
    bool swap;
    string temp;

    do
    {
        swap = false;
        for (int count = 1; count < (size - 1); count++)
        {
            if(array[count-1] >array[count])
            {
                temp = array[count-1];
                array[count-1] = array[count];
                array[count] = temp;
                swap = true;
            }
        }
    }
    while(swap);

}

void search(string *array, int size)
{
    int first = 0;
    int last = size - 1;
    int middle;
    string name;
    bool friends = false;

    do
    {
     cout<<"Please enter a name or END to terminate:";
     cin>>name;
    }
    while(!friends && first <= last && name != "END");
    {
        middle = (first + last) / 2;
        if (array[middle] == name)
            {
                friends = true;
                cout<<array[middle]<<" is my friend."<<endl;
            }
        else if (array[middle] > name)
            last = middle - 1;
        else
            last = middle + 1;
    }
 }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Searching a array of strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394020/searching-a-array-of-strings)

Comment: That was my question also, it had a few problems corrected and was suggested to start a new question.

Comment: In your sort function, `for (int count = 1; count < (size - 1); count++)` should be `for (int count = 1; count < size; count++);`

Comment: @jrok wouldn't this make me run past the number of elements in the array?

Comment: No, `count` will be smaller than `size` and you never acces index [count+1], so it's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't want to give too much away, since it's homework, so I'll move some of your code around, keeping it as close as possible, and show you why it currently won't work.

At the moment you're kind of thinking the `do...while` loop is some sort of double block, it's not. The code after the `while(...);` in your code will only be executed once, after you break out of the `do...while` loop, it's in no way connected. You're going to need two loops, an outer one that prompts for names, and an inner one that looks for that name in your list.

You're also not resetting `friends` and `last` after asking the user to enter another name. An easy fix is to move your declarations (which contain initialisations) inside the first loop.

This is what your code will look like after mostly rearranging it and apply the above changes:

```
void search(string *array, int size)
{
   string name;

   cout<<"Please enter a name or END to terminate:";
   cin>>name;

   while (name != "END")
   {
      bool friends = false;
      int first = 0;
      int last = size - 1;
      int middle;

      while(!friends && first <= last)
      {
         middle = (first + last) / 2;
         if (array[middle] == name)
         {
             friends = true;
             cout<<array[middle]<<" is my friend."<<endl;
         }
         else if (array[middle] > name)
            last = middle - 1;
         else
            last = middle + 1;
      }

      cout<<"Please enter another name or END to terminate:";
      cin>>name;
   }      
}
```

There's two different prompts this time, so that if the user enters `"END"`, the outside loop terminates immediately, rather than having to add an extra check inside the loop.

Also, as with your other question, `search(friendArray, maxsize);` should be `search(friendArray, sub);`, for the reason I told you last time - `sub` is a count of valid items in the array, `maxsize` is the capacity of the array.

**NOTE:** If the name doesn't exist in your list, it'll cause an infinite loop. I'll let you work that out since it's homework and I don't want to change any of your actual logic. A hint though is to think about what's actually happening - if a value doesn't exist you'll just keep incrementing and decrementing `last` around the area where the value should be if it existed.

Perhaps if your logic incorporated `first` being modified somewhere, so that the condition `first <= last` would fail and you'd break out of the loop...

Comment: Thanks mate but at the moment my logic is just not working, brain is fried but I will def. read this tomorrow.

Comment: @sircrisp: No worries. To elaborate on that hint, perhaps if you tried setting `first` or `last` to `middle` +- 1 depending on the whether the name is `<` or `>` the current element. The idea behind binary search is to shrink your search area each time, which is achieved by increasing the value of `first` and decreasing the value of `last`.

Answer (score 1):

Your do while statement is wrong, it run this order:

```
do
    {
     cout<<"Please enter a name or END to terminate:";
     cin>>name;
    }
    while(!friends && first <= last && name != "END");
```

And then this block:

```
{
    middle = (first + last) / 2;
    if (array[middle] == name)
        {
            friends = true;
            cout<<array[middle]<<" is my friend."<<endl;
        }
    else if (array[middle] > name)
        last = middle - 1;
    else
        last = middle + 1;
}
```

**Modify** it:

```
do
{
    cout<<"Please enter a name or END to terminate:";
    cin>>name;
    first = 0;
    last = size - 1;
    middle=0;
    friends = false;
    while(!friends && first <= last && name != "END");
    {
        middle = (first + last) / 2;
        if (array[middle] == name)
            {
                friends = true;
                cout<<array[middle]<<" is my friend."<<endl;
            }
        else if (array[middle] > name)
            last = middle - 1;
        else
            last = middle + 1;
    }

}
while(name != "END");
```

Comment: I changed the while to while(!friends && name != "END");                       No luck though. I've been working on this for 4 hours I can't pinpoint anything anymore my logic is deaddd.

Comment: Thanks for your help, after changing to your code my results are different but still not correct. I type in a name in the list and then nothing happens, no press key to continue, no enter name prompt, nothing. I can hear my CPU fan getting louder though.... ahh

Comment: You not show if search key is not found,So after while if friends=false and name!="END"  write cout<<"Not found".

Comment: I have done this but the problem is the same as before. What happens when you compile it?

Comment: @sircrisp: If the array isn't correctly ordered it can cause the binary-search to loop endlessly. Verify your `bubblesort()` by printing the array contents after sorting.

Comment: I agree with @Blastfurnace, Also i haven't editor and just guess.

Comment: I've changed it to temp = array[count-1];
    array[count-1] = array[count];
    array[count] = temp;
       swap = true;

Comment: Still doesn't work but I'm too tired I've been working on this for 5 hours it's just not worth it anymorreeee